# When you made alias in Apache Server you have to write Option: Indexes to Directiory?

Tags: php, apache, apache-config

When I don't give indexes option I all the time have forbidden message.
When I give this option it works well, but I don't have starting page, but page with head: "index of" and below it there are links to files, which are in my directory.

Now, how to do, that I will have starting page? Without error.

One note: When I don't use Aliasing, the test Apache page working well (as starting page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following line in your "alias" config:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```